# Centering rotated div inside container

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a `90deg` pricetag, however I'm unsure why it isn't doing what I want it to do, I want the tag to matchup with the top and right (top:0 and right:0).

It's not doing that,
**Code**

```
<div class='box'>
  <div class='price-tag'>
    $23.12
  </div>
</div>
.box{
  margin:10em;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
}

.box .price-tag{
  background:yellow;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 0%);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2vL6ch9/5/)

Comment: Could it be the `origin` of your transform - So it rotates slightly different than what you're expecting? If you modify the origin and then tweak the transform slightly, does it do what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/hbegvko5/ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to change the text direction by adjusting the [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.box .price-tag {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl; /* tb-rl if you want old browser support*/
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='price-tag'>
    $23.12
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When rotating any element by 90 degrees, what you're looking for is:

`transform: rotate(90deg) translate(calc(50% - (height/ 2)), calc(50% - (width/ 2)))`

Or more specific to this case:

`transform: rotate(90deg) translate(calc(50% - (18px / 2)), calc(50% - (44px / 2)))`

This is because when you rotate it, you'll want the `translate` to be off by `50%` on both the horizontal and vertical axis in order to position it back where it previously was. However, this only positions the **corner** where the previous position was.

To correct this, you'll also want to subtract **half** of the `height` from the new horizontal offset, and **half** of the `width` from the new vertical offset, making use of the **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** function.

This can be seen working in the following:

```css
.box {
  /*margin: 10em;*/ /* -- Removed for demo fiddle */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.box .price-tag {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(calc(50% - (18px / 2)), calc(50% - (44px / 2)))
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='price-tag'>
    $23.12
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `transform-origin`, you need to set it to `top right`

```css
.box {
  margin: 10em;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.box .price-tag {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='price-tag'>
    $23.12
  </div>
</div>
```